# c# wpf form within form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have just started c# and Wpf. I am trying to build a utility that gets computers from active directory, display them in a treeview and then recover information via WMI. I have managed to get most of this done without asking questions. However I now have a problem with presentation.[Current Wpf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZMxi.png)
after selecting the information required (disks/printers/services etc) i would like to display the information in the panel to the right. My problem is this infomation may be a tabbed form, a listbox, a gridview or a graphic.ex [A tab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCFP0.png)  What would be my best way to get this result. Thanks in advance.

It's the area currently taken up by " " that should show the different formats.

```
<StackPanel>
     <DockPanel Margin="3">
        <Border CornerRadius="6"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            Background="LightGray"
            BorderThickness="2" >
            <StackPanel  Background="SkyBlue" Height="80">
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Content="Domaine:"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30"/>
                    <TextBox Name="FrmDomain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30"  Width="80"/>

                    <Label Content="Zone" Height="30"/>
                    <TextBox Name="FrmTreeZone" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80"/>

                    <Label Content="Ordinateur:" />
                    <TextBox Name="FrmTreeOrdi" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80"/>

                    <Label Content="Option:" />
                    <TextBox Name="FrmTreeOption" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80" />
                    <Label Content="Disponible:" />
                    <TextBlock Name="FrmTreeAlive" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="40"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Content="Recherche:"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="FrmRecherche" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnRech" Click="btnRech_MouseClick" >
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Search"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Label Content="Mac:" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="FrmMac" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel Margin="3">
        <Border CornerRadius="6"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            Background="LightGray"
            BorderThickness="2" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="LightCyan" MinWidth="300" Width="300">
             <TreeView Name="FrmTreeView" Height="540" Margin="8" 
                      SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
                      PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                      TreeViewItem.Selected="NodeSelected">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="TestMenu">
                    </ContextMenu>

                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, 
                                            Path=Tag,
                                            Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance }}"/>
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <StackPanel  Name="test" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  Visibility="Visible">
            <Border CornerRadius="6"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            Background="WhiteSmoke"
            BorderThickness="2" >

                <TextBlock Name="FrmActionAffiche"  Height="540" Margin="8"/>

            </Border>
            <DataGrid Height="1" Name="FrmDataGrid"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="btnDisque" Content="Disque" Height="30" Width="100" Click="btnDisque_MouseClick" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="30">
        <StatusBar>
            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock>Ready</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
                <ProgressBar Value="30" Width="80" Height="18"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock>Set</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="3">
                <TextBlock>Go!</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: you will also need to post the C# code of all the relevant classes (the code behind for your XAML file, and the classes that are used as treeview items). Odds are the code will need to be changed as you're not using databinding and probably populating treeviewitems manually instead of letting the treeview do the work via binding (thus your selected item will probably only be raw text and not contain any of the data you need). It would be easiest, as i think your code will require heavy changes, if you could also post a zip of your solution on top of adding the code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to display different types of information in different ways you should make use of a DataTemplate, you can have multiple DataTemplates and select which one to display based on the type without any additional coding (or program your own logic for selecting the template with a DataTemplateSelector).

For example assuming the TreeView on the left contains items of type Computer and Printer you could bind a control to the SelectedItem property of the TreeView (do display the currently selected item) and add DataTemplates for Type=Printer and Type=Computer to that control to describe how you want to display either of them.

If you post your current code (XAML and C#) i'd be happy to give you an exemple for your specific case.